# Android XML Layouts crash app when elements moved around

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've been working on this XML layout for my Android app and it's gotten to a point where if I move elements around in the layout, the app crashes when I test it. (It works fine as I've pasted here)

I want to move the interior RelativeLayout 'characterSheetLayout' (and all of its children) so that it's a child of the outer wrapping RelativeLayout instead of where it is (So I can float it in the center when I call it from Java and make it visible, since its default visibility is Gone), but when I do that the app crashes and logcat states that there is an illegal state exception: Could not execute method of the activity.

I do not understand how moving around elements in the XML and changing nothing else can cause a method from my Java to break somehow.  Even moving the characterSheetButton at the bottom and trying to put it at the top causes seemingly the same error.

How can I move the characterSheetLayout RelativeLayout and its children to a place that will allow me to float it in the center of the screen?  Also, does anyone know why my app would crash just from moving these elements (which work fine as printed here) around?  Thank you for your time!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/topLinear1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/oldpaper"
android:layout_weight="1"

>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/characterSheetLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" 
            android:visibility="gone">




        <View
            android:id="@+id/topSpacer1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#60000000">
        </View>



        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/nameHeader"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Name:"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topSpacer1">
        </TextView>  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/nameDisplay"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topSpacer1">
        </TextView>     

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/healthHeader"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Health:"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameHeader">
        </TextView>  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/healthDisplay"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameHeader">
        </TextView>     

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/offenseHeader"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Offense:"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/healthHeader">
        </TextView>  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/offenseDisplay"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="3"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/healthHeader">
        </TextView>                 

         <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/defenseHeader"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Defense:"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/offenseHeader">
        </TextView>  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/defenseDisplay"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="2"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/offenseHeader">
        </TextView>                

          <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/moneyHeader"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Money:"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/defenseHeader">
        </TextView>  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/moneyDisplay"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="10"  
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/defenseHeader">
        </TextView>             





        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomSpacer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/moneyHeader">

       </View>








   </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton2"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton3"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton4"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/menuButton5"
    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

     />



</LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/characterSheetButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="View Character Sheet"

    />



        </LinearLayout>  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just wondering if I didn't explain anything properly.  Been viewed 15 times in the last day but no response.  Any info needed I'd be happy to post.  Is it that unusual for an application to crash when simply rearranging XML layouts?

Comment: You probably don't need the answer anymore, but still. It can happen from time to time that Eclipse doesn't register your XML layout change, so you should manually clean your project (Project -> Clean -> Select your project) and it should work.